# Prevent Leaflet .flyTo() animation stop when map clicked

Tags: leaflet

The default behavior of Leaflet's map.flyTo() method is that if the user clicks on the map during the flyTo animation, the animation stops.

I would like to keep the map animating until the desired view is reached, regardless of user interaction.

Is there a way to disable the map mouse/touch interactions for the duration of the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the methods described by @IvanSanchez within the function that fires theflyTo() method (let's call this function "triggersFlyTo()")and the 'moveend' event. I hope that the following code solves your problem:

```
//stop user interaction when flyTo() is fired

function triggersFlyTo() {
...
map.dragging.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
map.flyTo(...)
...
}


//restart user interaction when the "flying" stops. 

map.on('moveend', function() {
map.dragging.enable();
map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable the map mouse/touch interactions for the duration of the animation?

You probably want to temporarily disable the interaction *handlers*, like so:

```
map.dragging.disable();
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

...

map.dragging.enable();
map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
```

Check the full list at http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-handlers , along with the rest of the documentation.